# How to remove spplot() polygon fill in R

Tags: r

When I 'spplot' a SHP polygon imported with readOGR, the darned thing is always color filled. The color bar shows that it is using the shapefile ID value, with a single value.

Is there a way to get rid of the ID value and fill?

Thanks!

Comment: Something like this? `spplot(SpDF, fill=NA, colorkey=FALSE)`

Comment: Exactly like that, thanks Josh

Comment: @JoshO'Brien could you add that as an answer?

Comment: @PaulHiemstra -- Would you please add it? It's late here and I'm busy helping my wife grade papers... Thanks ;)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Done! Good luck helping your wife grading the papers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @JoshO'Brien said:

```
spplot(SpDF, fill = NA, colorkey = FALSE)
```

Does what you need.